# How to check if pid belongs to current user session?

Tags: c, macos, unix, macos-carbon, freebsd

I can get the list of running process from the [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92971-bsd-processes-with-code.html) source code on mac.

Now, I want to filter these processes for different users or at least for current user session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extend your code like this..

```
    kinfo_proc *mylist;
    size_t mycount = 0;
    mylist = (kinfo_proc *)malloc(sizeof(kinfo_proc));
    GetBSDProcessList(&mylist, &mycount);

    char *user  = getenv("USER");

    for (int i = 0; i < mycount; i++) 
    {       
        uid_t uid = mylist[i].kp_eproc.e_pcred.p_ruid;
        struct passwd * pwd = getpwuid(uid);
        char    * username = pwd->pw_name;

        if(strcmp(username, user) == 0)
        {
            printf(" %d - %s \n", mylist[i].kp_proc.p_pid, mylist[i].kp_proc.p_comm);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise you can get username buy this technique

```
    SCDynamicStoreRef   store;  
    store = SCDynamicStoreCreate(NULL, CFSTR("com.apple.dts.ConsoleUser"), NULL, NULL);
    CFStringRef  currentConsoleUser = CopyCurrentConsoleUsername(store);

    const int kBufferSize = 256;
    char logedinusername[kBufferSize];
    CFStringGetCString(currentConsoleUser,logedinusername,kBufferSize,kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);
```

as  getenv("USER"); may not work if you are running as root user and want logged in user.